App widget is not opening the wight activity
I'm having a problem that whenever I press any button on the app widget always opens the launcher activity instead of the acvitity I pretend. Even when I press the app widget anywhere opens the launcher activity.
I want that the several buttons on app widget open different activities.
This is the manifest:
    <receiver
        android:name=".Widget"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

This is the widget class:
class Widget : AppWidgetProvider() {
override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {

    appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            Intent(context, WidgetControl::class.java),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val views: RemoteViews = RemoteViews(
            context.packageName,
            R.layout.widget
        ).apply {
            setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.LLstartStop, pendingIntent)
        }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }
}

Right now I just one button and it opens the launcher activity instead of "WidgetControl::class.java" but I want to have two more. Even if I press anywhere in the app widget always opens the launcher activity.
